# SSIS Package to Move File to "Archive" Subdirectory in SFTP

Tags: ssis, sftp

I have a SSIS package that pulls down a CSV file from a client's SFTP directory. This step in the process works correctly. However, once the file is brought down, I want move it into the /Archive subdirectory.

I am using WS_FTP command line interface via an execute process task

I have the following statement at the end of my expression:

```
  -move \"/Archive\" -quiet"
```

But this doesn't seem to want to move it. I've also tried the entire directory location with no luck.

I'm wondering if the username I am using has the permissions to make the automated file move. I am able to move the file manually in FileZilla with the same account.

Is there anything else I can try before pushing back for upgraded permissions on the account?

Comment: What "expression" do you mean? What SFTP solution are you using? SSIS has no native SFTP support. You must be using some custom SFTP solution. How can we help you, if you do not tell us what is it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry about that. I am using WS_FTP command line interface via an execute process task.